is it possible to use chop n drop and compost instead of animal manure?
As the title states, we grow fruit trees in the wet humid tropics in ecuador but we see great result when we buy animal manure, however this increases the bottom line of those that raise animals and it is not sustainable. so i wonder if there is better way in addition to using chop n drop like nitrogen fixing plants like ice cream bean and flemingea and mexican sunflower (phosphorus accumulator)
Thanks!
